# Creating a ZIP file in memory with System.IO.Packaging.Package

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Currently i'm trying to create a zip-file within my memory. I collect many files

```
byte[] item1 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\1.gif");
byte[] item2 = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\2.gif");
```

and in a second step I want to add them to one zip file and save that zip file

```
byte[] result = AddFilesToZip(new byte[][] { item1, item2 });
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\images.zip", result);
```

Here is my approach `AddFilesToZip`:

```
public static byte[] AddFilesToZip(byte[][] filesToAdd)
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream())
    {
    using (System.IO.Packaging.Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(result, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesToAdd.Length; i++)
        {
            System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart ZipPart = zip.CreatePart(new Uri(i + ".gif"), MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption.Normal);
            ZipPart.GetStream().Write(filesToAdd[i], 0, filesToAdd[i].Length);
        }
    }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But I already get an error, that URI is invalid at `new Uri(i + ".gif")`.

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: Does it work if you do `.Open(result, System.IO.FileMode.Create)`?

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace rather than just the error message... otherwise we don't know where it's failing.

Comment: @DaisyShipton done

Comment: No, that's not the complete stack trace. A stack trace will include a bunch of lines showing the method being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you will need a relative URI, but the Uri class doesn't know what kind of Uri you're creating.

Try this instead:

```
new Uri("/" + i + ".gif", UriKind.Relative)
```